# RenderTargetBitmap without putting it on UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, rendertargetbitmap

I want to create a universal app in Visual Studio 2013 that creates an image from a `Canvas` that is generated with code dynamically. If I display the canvas on the UI (in a `Grid`, for example) it's alright. If I don't display the canvas, the app crashes with the message:

> value does not fall within the expected range.

There is the code that i use:

```
Canvas cn = new Canvas();
cn.Height = 100;
cn.Width = 100;
cn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
Button but = new Button();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Width = 100;
rect.Height = 100;
rect.Margin = new Thickness(0);
SolidColorBrush bruch = new SolidColorBrush();
bruch.Color = Colors.Blue;
rect.Fill = bruch;
but.Width = 50;
but.Height = 50;
but.Content = "23";
but.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
cn.Children.Add(rect);
cn.Children.Add(but);
but.Margin = new Thickness(25, 25, 0, 0);
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(cn, 100, 100);
outputImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
```

I don't want to display the canvas on the UI because I plan to use this code from a `BackgroundTask`.

Here is my [sample project](http://1drv.ms/1y7nvWI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone apps can use the [XamlRenderingBackgroundTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.aspx) to render in a background task. C++ is recommended for the background task to keep resource usage low.

See the [Updating a tile from a background task](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Updating-a-tile-from-a-e0e492df) sample for an example.

XamlRenderingBackgroundTask is not supported for Windows Store apps. On Windows the RenderTargetBitmap cannot be used from a background task and requires that the target UIElement be in the main visual tree.

Comment: It appears that this is still the case in Win10... Is there any other way to render an image from a background task at this moment ?

Comment: If by Win10 you mean a UWP app then you can use XamlRenderingBackgroundTask. It's in the Universal API Contract. If you mean a Windows 8.x app running on Win10 then there's no change and it's not available.

Comment: I am using XamlRenderingBackgroundTask but even there, you cannot use RenderTargetBitmap to render a control that is not in the visual tree..and I don't have a visual tree in a background task. Unless there's another way....

Comment: Calling RenderTargetBitmap on loose Xaml in a background task is specifically the point of XamlRenderingBackgroundTask. Take a look at the sample I linked, and if you still have trouble post a new question with details of what you've tried, what's going wrong, etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the sample again. I figured it out from that!!  The key is to create a root element by using XamlReader.Parse and put your controls in there. If you simply instantiate the control it RenderTargetBitmap will throw an ArgumentException.